# Load SVG with image in Skiasharp

Tags: c#, svg, .net-core, skiasharp

How can I render a Jpeg from SVG with SkiaSharp? The SVG includes a Jpeg. 
When I open the file in a browser, the image will show, but the Jpeg produced by SkiaSharp excludes the Jpg I want to include. The rest of the SVG renders fine.

This is the SVG:

```
<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g>
  <g id="svg_3">
   <image width="225" height="100" xlink:href="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/MnyjX3S.jpg" transform="matrix(2.54667, 0, 0, 2.57, 402.947, 108.409)" id="svg_53402_5" y="-14.5428" x="-155.85733"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

The code used to render the jpg looks like this:

```
    public static byte[] Svg2Jpg(MemoryStream svgReader)
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var svg = new SKSvg(new SKSize(1000, 1000));

        try
        {
            svgReader.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            svg.Load(svgReader);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

        var bitmap = new SKBitmap((int)svg.CanvasSize.Width, (int)svg.CanvasSize.Height);
        var canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);
        canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);

        canvas.Flush();
        canvas.Save();

        using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap))
        using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 80))
        {
            data.SaveTo(output);
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: So you want to extract the jpg filename from the XML (SVG)?

Comment: No, I want to generate a jpg from a svg. The svg includes a jpg, but will not be included in the jpg created from the svg. All other elements are displayed.

Comment: You would need a SVG viewer.  In this case you have a rectangle that is the background (use a picturebox), jpg image, and a title (use a panel and put title on panel which you can use instead of a rectangle).

Comment: I have edited the svg to better explain what I need. I want to load the svg, convert it to jpg and save it.

Comment: Skiasharp doesn't recognize xml format so you have to extract data and put into Skiasharp.